# Traefik with Docker Networks

Tags: docker, traefik

I really don't get how to use traefik with docker networks.

I try to run "wekan" kanban. If I bind ports to host, it works perfectly, so it really is about adressing it through traefik. Here is my docker-config:

```
version: '2'

services:

 wekandb:
   image: mongo:3.2.14
   container_name: wekan-db
   command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
   networks:
     - wekan-tier
   expose:
     - 27017
   volumes:
     - wekan-db:/data/db
     - wekan-db-dump:/dump

 wekan:
   image: wekanteam/wekan:latest
   container_name: wekan-app
   networks:
     - wekan-tier
#    ports:
#      - 8081:80
   environment:
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://wekandb:27017/wekan
     - ROOT_URL=https://wekan.domain.com
   depends_on:
     - wekandb
   labels:
     - "traefik.port=80"
     - "traefik.backend=wekan"
     - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wekan.domain.com"
     - "traefik.docker.network=wekan_wekan-tier"
volumes:
 wekan-db:
   driver: local
 wekan-db-dump:
   driver: local

networks:
 wekan-tier:
   driver: bridge
```

I can't seem to find a way to access the damn thing... Your answer will be greatly appreciated, not only will it allow me to run Wekan, but also to update my older services where I used linking:linking instead of Docker Networks - Linking being now deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you have more than one issue here.

First, in your compose you don't have Traefik service, it is OK, Traefik will be able to see containers from the services here, but Traefik will not be able to send the request to it, because Traefik service and wekan service does not share the same network.

So to fix that you need to create an specific network to Traefik and set it in your compose file also.

Example:

```
$ docker network create traefik-net
$ docker service --name traefik --network traefik-net .... traefik ....
```

Second, you need to define the network Traefik will use to connect with your service, this network must be one shared with Traefik service.

So your wekan service needs to be like this:

```
 wekan:
   image: wekanteam/wekan:latest
   container_name: wekan-app
   networks:
     - wekan-tier
     - traefik-net
   environment:
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://wekandb:27017/wekan
     - ROOT_URL=https://wekan.domain.com
   depends_on:
     - wekandb
   labels:
     - "traefik.port=80"
     - "traefik.backend=wekan"
     - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wekan.domain.com"
     - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your docker-compose file to make it work:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    image: wekanteam/wekan:latest
    networks:
    - wekan-tier
    environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://wekandb:27017/wekan
    - ROOT_URL=https://wekan.domain.com
    labels:
    - "traefik.port=80"
    - "traefik.docker.network=wekan_wekan-tier"

  wekandb:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
    networks:
    - wekan-tier
    expose:
    - 27017
    volumes:
    - wekan-db:/data/db
    - wekan-db-dump:/dump

  traefik:
    image: 'traefik:1.6'
    command: --web --docker --docker.watch --docker.domain=local --logLevel=DEBUG
    labels:
    - traefik.docker.network=wekan-tier
    - traefik.port=8080
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
    - wekan-tier

volumes:
  wekan-db:
    driver: local
  wekan-db-dump:
    driver: local

networks:
  wekan-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Now start containers with the following command:

```
$ docker-compose -p wekan up -d
```

To check that `traefik` is working go to http://localhost:8080/, if you have problems stop your apache server using `$ service apache2 stop`. On the other hand, if you can see the traefik interface then add the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   web.wekan.local
```

Now go to http://web.wekan.local and you should see Wekan login page :)